# Read and plot from csv with a counter

Tags: python, csv, count, grouping

Hello I have a csv with data for 25 bridges that have undergone maintenance from 1992-2016.

[image: Bridge.csv]

The first column corresponds to the bridge number. The next 25 columns corresponds to the condition ratings from 1992 to 2016. If the condition rating increased, that means the bridge underwent maintenance.
Now that I've figured out how to get the amount of times each bridge underwent maintenance, I have to create an input that allows users to input any year from 1992-2016 and then print the total number of bridges who's maintenance count increased. I believe it will be a separate "if" statement at the end like such.

```
f = open("BridgeExam1.csv", "r")
year = int(input("Please give a year between 1992 - 2016: "))

for line in f:   
    temp = line.split(",")
    i = 1
    maintenance = 0
    while i < len(temp) - 1:
        if  int(temp[i]) < int(temp[i+1]):
            maintenance+=1 
        i = i+1 
        temp[0]=temp[0] + 1992
    print("Bridge "+ temp[0], maintenance)                                      
f.close()
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add some of the rows from the csv file to it so folks have something runnable and can use it for testing solutions.

Comment: Good Idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do. Outputs the bridge number and the number of times it has undergone maintenance

```
f = open("BridgeExam1.csv", "r")
for line in f:   
    temp = line.split(",")
    i = 1
    maintenance = 0
    while i < len(temp) - 1:
        if  int(temp[i]) < int(temp[i+1]):
            maintenance+=1 
        i = i+1 
    print("Bridge "+ temp[0], maintenance)                                      
f.close()
```

Comment: That's perfect. I kept getting caught up in running a counter but it was stuck in the while loop and throwing wild data. Thanks